# Givng a dynamic file name while saving CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, file, dynamic

So, I am trying to convert multiple PDFs into CSV. I have a code that does the scanning and transforms everything into a single CSV as of now. However, instead of converting the data into one single CSV, I want Python to save individual CSVs for each PDF processed (this is primarily to identify a new file as there is more code on top of this that formats the data). I have the below code now, but I can't find a way to save multiple files. Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
import os
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

directory = r'Folfer Path'

lines = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf = os.path.join(directory, filename)


        with pdfplumber.open(pdf) as pdf:
            pages = pdf.pages
            for page in pdf.pages:
                text = page.extract_text()
                for line in text.split('\n'):
                    lines.append(line)
                    print(line)

            df = pd.DataFrame(lines)

df.to_csv('Folder Path/ filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
directory = r'pdfs'
csv_dir = r"csvs"
lines = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf_file:
            for page in pdf_file.pages:
                text = page.extract_text()
                for line in text.split('\n'):
                    lines.append(line)
                df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
            df.to_csv(os.path.join(csv_dir, filename[0:-4] + ".csv"))
```

That might an answer to your problem.
You have some indentation problems and non-dynamic file names.
In this code, the CSV files will be saved to a folder 'csvFiles', make sure you create it before running the code. it should be looking like that:
Path...

- path..
- your python script file (.py)
- pdfs(Folder)

  - pdf1.pdf
  - pdf2.pdf
  - ...
- csvs(Folder)

  - csv1.csv
  - csv2.csv
  - ...